# Angular ERROR in src/app/koszyk.service.ts(21,28): error TS2339: Property 'przedmioty' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: javascript, angular, properties, compiler-errors

An error pops up in my app

> ERROR in src/app/koszyk.service.ts(21,28): error TS2339: Property 'przedmioty' does not exist on type '{}'.

(on the left my code, on the right original code from curse)

[Photo problem 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl3lh.png)

problem is with x.przedmioty

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js">

async pobierzKoszyk(): Promise <Observable<Koszyk>> {
    let koszykId = await this.pobierzLubUtworzKoszykId();
    return this.db.object('/koszyki/' + koszykId).valueChanges()
    .map(x => new Koszyk(x.przedmioty));
  }

</script>
```

Please help me. I wrote the whole application and I have only one problem.

And one more during compiling:

"Refused to load the font '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback."

[Photo problem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnWC3.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should separate your two questions into two separate SO-Questions, since they seem to be quite different and not related.

The error clearly indicates what's wrong: `przedmioty` doesn't exist on  `x`.
What is `x`and what does it look like?

It seems to me that `x` is an empty object. Maybe the record queried doesn't exist on FireBase, you would need to check for that in your code.

But I don't know FireBase